# AWS: Invalid storage size for engine name postgres

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a RDS instance in amazon I want to modify the allocated storage for, it's currently at 500GB but I want it at 50GB. However when I try changing this in the console I receive the following error: `Invalid storage size for engine name postgres and storage type standard: 60`

I have a Elasticbeanstalk application that had no RDS instance associated with it, after reading around I've read that some people needed to have an instance with the same specs as the RDS you're trying to modify, however that didn't work either.

Any help here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You **can't decrease** allocate storage for your RDS. It can only be increased. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html):

> **You can only increase** the allocated storage. You **can't reduce** the allocated storage.

You would have to migrate your database to new RDS instance with smaller storage.

Comment: I see, I didn't even see that. Thank you, so I guess the solution for me would be to create a new database from a snapshot with a smaller allocation amount? Is that possible?

Comment: @CharlesSmith No problem. I don't think so. Snapshot will most likely also require at least same storage or greater.

Comment: So there's no way to retain all the same data from my old RDS instance in new instance with a smaller allocation limit??

Comment: You have to migrate it. Not sure about postgresql. In mysql, one could use `mysqldump` and resotre in new one. You have to check what options are there for migrating databases from RDS. Maybe there is some one-click solution. I'm not sure.

Comment: Looks like you're right, luckily AWS has their Migration Service so that should work. Thanks again

Comment: Another option is to launch a read replica with the smaller volume size, then promote it to a stand alone and drop the old master.

Comment: @Justin Are you sure you can make replica smaller? Do you have any docs for that or tried to do it?

Comment: I can't seem to find any options/documentation for it, so maybe I'm mis-remembering.  I've seen cases where the replica is smaller, but those must be a result of increasing size on the masters without updating the replicas.  So, it's technically something that can be done, but not something that is allowed during new replica creation.  DMS seems like the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

According to the documentation,  [Working with storage for Amazon RDS DB instances:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PIOPS.StorageTypes.html)

"When you increase the allocated storage, it must be by at least 10 percent. If you try to increase the value by less than 10 percent, you get an error."

Increase it by 550.

If you try to increase the value by less than 10 percent, you get an error. Try with a bigger increment and it should work.

AWS link:

https://repost.aws/questions/QU-nttnwVuTUGHaA90PMvDGA/rds-storage-upgrade-failure-error-error-modifying-db-instance-invalid-parameter-combination-invalid-storage-size-for-engine-name-postgres-and-storage-type-gp-2-2400

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a curious version of the `You can't reduce the allocated storage` issue.

DBInstance definition in cloudformation included `AllocatedStorage: nn` and `MaxAllocatedStorage: nnnn`. Then I wanted to redeploy changing the DBInstanceClass and got this error.

The problem was that the DB grew above the allocated storage, so seems that by deploying a new instance with the original allocated storage I was trying to reduce it below the actual currently allocated storage.

Solution was to check the size of the latest DB snapshot and update the Cloudformation `AllocatedStorage` property with it.